# Why does a newline character in textview cause the newline to be indented?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-3.0-honeycomb

```
<string
     This is a test\n
     This is another line.
/>
```

I try to show this in a textview when the newline (or the white space before the start of the next line) causes the new line to be indented by 1 blank space. Show basically this looks like -

> This is a test
>
> `This is another line`

Why is this happening and how do I fix this? Any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it has to do with the extra whitespace you are adding yourself in the characters.  I would guess that Android is treating all of your extra whitespace as a single space (it may also be a function of the parser, I am not sure).

I think you would rather do something like this to get what you are expecting.

```
<resources>
    <string name="test_str">This is a test\nThis is another line.</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I had this same issue a while ago, I'm pretty sure this is how I fixed it.

Comment: yep thats what I did.. just wanted to make it more readable in the resource file..